# PHP: string to regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try use string as a regular expression pattern but I've following errors

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '>' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cruncher/Plugins/wordpress/WPDetect.php on line 22
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cruncher/Plugins/wordpress/WPDetect.php on line 22
```

The code

```
$str = "<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"WordPress.com\" />"
preg_match("/".$str."/", $content->content)
```

I also tried to use `preg_quote` function but I've similar problems.

What is the correct way to make it work?

Sultan

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `preg_quote` function and pattern enclosed with `|...|`

```
preg_match("|" . preg_quote($str, "|") . "|", $content->content)
```

Comment: Ok sorry did'n tknow there was a time limit :)

Comment: This will fail as soon as `$str` contains a `|`. My advice is to *always* supply the second argument. In this case: `'|'.preg_quote($str, '|').'|'`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
$pattern = "/" . preg_quote($source, "/") . "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must escape your limiter

```
$str = "<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"WordPress.com\" \/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression contain a set of special char like \ - * . ? $ ^ + () []and more, you have to escape them from your string before using it (you esacpe by adding a \ before the char)