# Escaping regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have regexes stored in a txt file. How do I escape them in PHP? preg_quote doesn't help if I use the output in an array, throws fatal error. (The following each are on new lines in the txt file)

```
/[^a-z\/'"]eval\([^\)]+['"\s\);]+/i
/\$auth_pass\s*=.+;/i
/document\.write\((['"])<iframe .+<\/iframe>\1\);*/i
/preg_replace\s*\(.+[\/\#\|][i]*e[i]*['"].+\)/i
/<\?.+?exec\(.+?system\(.+?passthru\(.+fwrite\(.+/s
/RewriteRule [^ ]+ http\:\/\/(?!127\.).*/i
/<\?[\shp]*\@?error_reporting\(0\);.+?[a-z0-9\/\-\='"\.]{2000}.*?($|\?>)/i
/\<a [^\>]+\>\<span style="color\:\#F1EFE4;"\>(.+?)\<\/span\>\<\/a\>\<span style="color\:\#F1EFE4;"\>(.+?)\<\/span\>/i
/(<!\d)\$[\$\{]*[a-z\-\_0-9]+[\} \t]*(\[[^\]]+\][ \t]*)*\(.*?\)\;/i
/\#(\w+)\#.+?\#\/\1\#/is
/(\$[a-z_0-9]+[=\s\@]+)?create_function\([^,]+,[\s\$\.\[\]a-z_0-9]+[\s\)]+;*/i
/json2\.min\.js/i
/(RewriteCond \%\{HTTP_USER_AGENT\} .+\s+)+RewriteRule \^.*\$ http:\/\/(?!127\.).*/i
/<title>[^<]*hack[3e][rd]/i
```

Comment: What does this even mean? _preg_quote doesn't help if I use the output in an array, throws fatal error_ Do you have some code that throws an error that you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to adjust your call to preg_quote(). Something like this:

`Preg_match("|" . preg_quote($str, "|") . "|", $content->content)`

See another post with a similar question:

[PHP String to Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873144/php-string-to-regex)

Comment: The beer is on me :)